# What is the limit on automatic storage on OS X in Obj-C, and why do I need to use malloc instead of a normal auto array for large arrays?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos

I came across a strange error today, and I still don't understand it:

```
long long N = 2000;
long long N2 = N*N;
long long *s = malloc(sizeof(long long)*N2); // create array
// populate it
for (long long k = 1; k <= 55; k++) {
```

doesn't produce any errors, but

```
long long N = 2000;
long long N2 = N*N;
long long s[4000000]; // create array
// populate it
for (long long k = 1; k <= 55; k++) {
```

gives me a code=2 EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `for` line *before* assigning 1 to k (according to the debugger), as if there was no space left to allocate another 8-byte variable.  This code is at the beginning of a method; no other variables have been assigned or allocated.  I'm guessing that I simply can't allocate a 4000000-element long long array to the stack, but somehow I can allocate it to the dynamic heap.  Could someone please explain what's going on, what the limits are, etc.?  This is Objective-C on a Mac running Mountain Lion, 2GB RAM.  A long long is 8 bytes wide, so the array should only be 32MB; I can't see why this should be an issue.

Thank you!

(By the way, if the details look familiar, it's because this is the beginning of my solver for Project Euler's [Problem 149](http://projecteuler.net/problem=149).  I've avoided mentioning any details of the solution here, as I've solved the problem already.)

Comment: The stack is 8 MB by default. Use `ulimit -s` to check.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example allocates memory from the heap, which is in the “data segment”, and your second allocates memory on the stack, which is in the “stack segment”.  Each of these has a different size limit.

The default stack segment size limit, according to [Technical Q&A QA1419](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1419/_index.html), is 8 MiB.  You can double-check this by running `ulimit -a` in a terminal:

```
:; ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

As you can see, the stack size is limited to 8192 KiB = 8 MiB.

The Technical Q&A I linked above describes some ways to increase the stack size limit.  The maximum to which you can increase it without running as root is 64 MiB.

If you create threads, each thread gets its own stack.  According to the Q&A, you can set a thread's stack size up to 1 GiB if you use the `NSThread` API.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer -- I'm now aware of stack size restrictions!

Answer (score 2):

Auto locals are allocated on the stack; according to [this technical note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1419/_index.html), the default stack size for an OSX process's main thread is 8MB, and less for additional threads. You can try the linker option or `setrlimit` solutions given in the note, but C tradition is to use the heap for any large allocations.